# How to validate an Ethereum address PHP / Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-5, ethereum

How can I check if the Ethereum address from Laravel input is valid in terms of format?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a Laravel [custom validation rule](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#using-rule-objects) for validating Ethereum addresses against the [EIP 55](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-55.md) specification. For details of how it works, please go through the comments.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Rules;

use kornrunner\Keccak; // composer require greensea/keccak
use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;

class ValidEthereumAddress implements Rule
{
    /**
     * @var Keccak
     */
    protected $hasher;

    public function __construct(Keccak $hasher)
    {
        $this->keccak = $hasher;
    }

    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        // See: https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/blob/7935e5f/lib/utils/utils.js#L415
        if ($this->matchesPattern($value)) {
            return $this->isAllSameCaps($value) ?: $this->isValidChecksum($value);
        }

        return false;
    }

    public function message()
    {
        return 'The :attribute must be a valid Ethereum address.';
    }

    protected function matchesPattern(string $address): int
    {
        return preg_match('/^(0x)?[0-9a-f]{40}$/i', $address);
    }

    protected function isAllSameCaps(string $address): bool
    {
        return preg_match('/^(0x)?[0-9a-f]{40}$/', $address) || preg_match('/^(0x)?[0-9A-F]{40}$/', $address);
    }

    protected function isValidChecksum($address)
    {
        $address = str_replace('0x', '', $address);
        $hash = $this->keccak->hash(strtolower($address), 256);

        // See: https://github.com/web3j/web3j/pull/134/files#diff-db8702981afff54d3de6a913f13b7be4R42
        for ($i = 0; $i < 40; $i++ ) {
            if (ctype_alpha($address{$i})) {
                // Each uppercase letter should correlate with a first bit of 1 in the hash char with the same index,
                // and each lowercase letter with a 0 bit.
                $charInt = intval($hash{$i}, 16);

                if ((ctype_upper($address{$i}) && $charInt <= 7) || (ctype_lower($address{$i}) && $charInt > 7)) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

#### Dependencies

To validate checksum addresses, we need a [Keccac](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/550) implementation in place which is not supported by the built-in [`hash()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/de/function.hash.php) function. You need to require [this pure PHP implementation](https://github.com/greensea/php-keccak) for the above rule to work.

Comment: It is not working correctly. if you check this valid address then also it will showing invalid i.e. `0x7614e80bE7E0C1e5aFce4E8e35627dEEc461d2bD`

Comment: There was a problem with the hashing algorithm here. Ethereum uses a variant of SHA3 with different padding constant called Keccak. I've updated the answer. Kudos to @WebSpanner for pointing it out.

Comment: @DhavalBharadva ,, are you sure it is valid Ethereum address?

Answer (score 0):

Any 42 character string starting with 0x, and following with 0-9, A-F, a-f (valid hex characters) represent a valid Ethereum address.

You can find more information about lowercase and partial uppercase (for adding checksum) Ethereum addresses format [here](https://theethereum.wiki/w/index.php/Accounts,_Addresses,_Public_And_Private_Keys,_And_Tokens#Account_or_Address).

Comment: thanx for reply, I am use go-ethereum JSON RPC API concept  but no any function to validate the address.

Comment: Yes, it is simpler than need a new api call. You can do that with just one line of code. For example with python re module:
True if re.match("^(0x)?[0-9a-f]{40}$", address) else False

Answer (score 0):

As of Laravel 9, If you are using a request class for validation, add this to the validation rules:

```php
/**
 * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
 * 
 * @return array
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'address' => 'regex:/^(0x)?(?i:[0-9a-f]){40}$/'
    ];
}
```

Notes:

- Here, the input field name is *address*
- I applied case insensitivity to only a part of the regular expression using the format `(?i: ... )`